# If I can linearly map a metric onto the Minkowski metric, then is the original metric automatically flat?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, curvature

Suppose I have a metric $g$ such that, via a linear coordinate transformation (i.e. a transformation represented by a non-singular matrix, not necessarily diagonal), I can rewrite $g$ as the Minkowski metric $\eta$ but in terms of these new coordinates, then can I guarantee that the Riemann curvature tensor is zero for the original metric? Would this mean that my original metric is flat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

In the new coordinate system , we would get $${R^d}_{abc}=0$$
at every point on the manifold.

This is a tensor relation, so it holds in any coordinate system. This means that the curvature tensor is also zero in the orignial coordinate system.

We then say that the vanishing of the curvature tensor (in any coordinate system) is a necessary and sufficient condition for the manifold to be flat.

In fact, a manifold *is defined* to be flat if there exists coordinates $X^\mu$ such that, throughout the manifold, the line element can be written as
$$ds^2=\epsilon_1(dX^1)^2+\epsilon_2(dX^2)^2+...+\epsilon_N(dx^N)^2$$
where $\epsilon_a=\pm1.$

Comment: Is this a function of the linearity of the coordinate transformation?

Comment: What do you mean by function?

Comment: Actually, the fact that ${R^d}_{abc}=0$ implies that it is possible to introduce a coordinate system where the line element is $ds^2=\epsilon_1(dX^1)^2+\epsilon_2(dX^2)^2+...+\epsilon_N(dx^N)^2$. You can look up the proof if interested.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any metric that can be transformed into the Minkowski metric via coordinate transformations must be the same physical metric, and hence is flat (vanishing curvature).